# Display print_r vertically after explode

Tags: php

[EDIT: This may be a duplicate question...but I spent over 30 minutes looking for the answer to this question and did not find on stackoverflow. I would argue my question is more specific]

A standard PHP string to explode to print_r:

```
<?php

    $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3";
    $pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
    print_r($pieces);
?>
```

Does anybody know the magic of making this output:

```
Array ( [0] => piece1 [1] => piece2 [2] => piece3)
```

Turn into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => piece1
    [1] => piece2
    [2] => piece3
)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: The `<pre></pre>` tag

Comment: @Tez You can get this output using `echo "<pre>";print_r($pieces);echo </pre>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($pizza);
print "</pre>";
```

Or

```
print nl2br(print_r($pizza, true));
```